# How to attach any file as an attachment to a JIRA issue by java code?

Tags: java, attachment, jira, issue-tracking, jira-plugin

Any Ideas on how to programatically attach a File to an issue in JIRA? 
**I need java code** which should be called at end of my code so that it can upload my report files to an existing issue automatically...

Im new to JIRA...

Answer (score 1):

MangaerFactory is deprecated on from jira 5.x, so it is good use

```
AttachmentManager attchMgr = ComponentAccessor.getAttachmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

The AttachmentsManager can be used to attach a JAVA File object to a JIRA issue.

```
import java.io.File;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.AttachmentManager;
import com.opensymphony.user.User;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean;
...
File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
AttachmentManager attachmentManager = ManagerFactory.getAttachmentManager();
ChangeItemBean changeItemBean = attachmentManager.createAttachment(file, file.getName(), "text/plain", user, issue.getGenericValue, new HashMap(), timestamp);
```

Source: http://docs.servicerocket.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1711